# NoSuchElementException error for ATM Machine app (Modified)

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am currently learning Java and I am trying to retain the information I learned by building a ATM machine app (I plan on adding more to it in the future).
My current issue is I would like to ask a user 'What would you like to do' repeatedly until a valid input is provided(current valid inputs are 'Withdraw' and 'Deposit').

I have a loop that will repeatedly ask the user 'Please select a valid choice' if the input is not valid. If the input is valid it will execute only once, ask 'What would you like to do', and then display a NoSuchElementException. Not sure how to fix this.

Here is my code:

**App.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        boolean done = false;       

        while(!done) {
            System.out.println("What woul you like to do?");
            String response = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
            Transactions newTransaction = new Transactions();

            if (response.equals("withdraw")) {
                newTransaction.Withdrawal();
            } else if (response.equals("deposit")) {
                newTransaction.Deposit();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please select a valid choice");
            }   
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Transactions.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Transactions {
    private int currentBalance = 100;

    public void Withdrawal() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");

        int withdrawAmount = scanner.nextInt();

        if (withdrawAmount > 0) {
            if (currentBalance > 0) {

                currentBalance -= withdrawAmount;
                System.out.println("Amount withdrawn: $" + withdrawAmount);
                System.out.println("Current Balance: $" + Balance());
                if (currentBalance < 0) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "You have withdrawn more than you have in current balance.\nYou will be charged a overdraft fee");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "You have withdrawn more than you have in current balance.\nYou will be charged a overdraft fee");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't remove 0 from account");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    public void Deposit() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");

        int depositAmount = scanner.nextInt();

        if (depositAmount > 0) {
            currentBalance += depositAmount;
            Balance();
        }
        System.out.println("Amount deposited: $" + depositAmount);
        System.out.println("Current Balance: $" + Balance());

        scanner.close();
    }

    public int Balance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

[NoSuchElementException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZOS5.png)

Comment: You'll want to become familiar with the concept of a loop. You may want a `while` loop here.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I have looked at a while loop but was getting this error 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException' so I thought there might be another solution since I am not sure how to solve that error. I forgot to add that part to the question.

Comment: We would need more context regarding your previous implementation to tell you exactly what was happening with your `while` loop. It's possible the scope of the loop was giving you that exception. (Meaning the places you put your brackets and how the brackets could potentially be causing that issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sentinel. A sentinel is a value entered that will end the iteration.

```
//incomplete code showing logic
int choice;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Choice");
choice = input.nextInt();
while(choice != -1){  //-1 is the sentinel, can be value you choose
    //Some logic you want to do
    System.out.println("Enter choice or -1 to end");
    choice = input.NextInt();  //notice we input choice again here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like has been said you should learn about loops. There are two types while-loop and for-loop. In this case you should youse the while-loop.

The implementation of your problem could be this.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What woul you like to do?");
       
        String response;
        Transactions newTransaction = new Transactions();

        
        while (true) {
                response = scanner.next().toLowerCase();        
                if (response.equals("withdraw")) {
                    newTransaction.Withdrawal();
                    break;
                } else if (response.equals("deposit")) {
                    newTransaction.Deposit();
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please select a valid choice");        
                }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right. I was just missing the break statements. Thanks.